# Powershell "cannot index into a null array" error occurs within a function only

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I have the below error when I try to run a function that I create to summarise traffic. The weird thing is that when I run this code by itself (not invoking the function) it runs fine.

I noticed the problem when I call the function is when I try to use an index (example: $_[1])

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:13 char:79
+         $sumhumanvisits = ($humanvisits[0..($humanvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_ ...
+                                                                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:16 char:73
+         $sumbotvisits = ($botvisits[0..($botvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_[1]} | ...
+                                                                         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The code is this one

```
function Get-incapTraffic-90Days ($site_id,$id,$key){

        #Incapsula visits in last 90 days
        $r2 = Invoke-WebRequest ("https://my.incapsula.com/api/stats/v1?api_id=" + $id + "&api_key=" + $key + "&time_range=last_90_days&site_id=" + $site_id + "&stats=visits_timeseries") -Method Post
        $visits = $r2.Content | ConvertFrom-Json

        $humanvisits = @(($visits.visits_timeseries | Where-Object {$_.id -match "api.stats.visits_timeseries.human"} | Select-Object data).data)
        #$humanvisits = $visits.visits_timeseries[0].data
        $botvisits = @(($visits.visits_timeseries | Where-Object {$_.id -match "api.stats.visits_timeseries.bot"} | Select-Object data).data)
        #$botvisits = $visits.visits_timeseries[1].data

        #Summarize Human visits
        $sumhumanvisits = ($humanvisits[0..($humanvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_[1]} | measure -Sum).Sum

        #Summarize Bot visits
        $sumbotvisits = ($botvisits[0..($botvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_[1]} | measure -Sum).Sum


        if (($sumhumanvisits -gt 0) -and ($sumbotvisits -gt 0)){

            $traffic = $sumhumanvisits.ToString() + " Human + " + $sumbotvisits + " Bots Traffic"
        }
        elseif($sumhumanvisits -gt 0){

            $traffic = ($sumhumanvisits.ToString() + " Human traffic")

        }
        elseif($sumbotvisits -gt 0){

            $traffic = ($sumbotvisits.ToString() + " Bot traffic")
        }
        else{

            $traffic = "No traffic"
        }
        Return $traffic
}
```

The data store on the variable $humanvisits is below. And I need only to summarise the small values.

> ```
> 1564531200000
> 69
> 1571788800000
> 145
> 1565049600000
> 229
> 1569196800000
> 249
> 1569456000000
> 156
> 1568419200000
> 114
> 1567641600000
> 165
> ```

Comment: Can you give an example of what one of these look like?  There might be a different way to retrieve the values to avoid this scenario. I'm curious to see both `$humanvisits[0]` and `$botvisits[0]`.  Remember to sanitize it to not leak customer information.

Comment: is your `$humanvisits` sample really one line? is there no structure to it at all?

Comment: You are using the regex `-match` operator, but you do not escape the dots in the string to match against. Example `"api.stats.visits_timeseries.human"` should be `"api\.stats\.visits_timeseries\.human"`. If in doubt, use `[regex]::Escape()`

Comment: An example of the result of $humanvisits[0] is: 1564531200000
69. In this case I just need the value 69 for the summarize part as the first value is just a reference code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this error because you are using the regex `-match` operator, but you do not escape the dots in the string to match against.

Try:

```
$reHuman = [regex]::Escape("api.stats.visits_timeseries.human")
$reBot   = [regex]::Escape("api.stats.visits_timeseries.bot")
$humanvisits = @(($visits.visits_timeseries | Where-Object {$_.id -match $reHuman} | Select-Object data).data)
$botvisits = @(($visits.visits_timeseries | Where-Object {$_.id -match $reBot} | Select-Object data).data)
```

Comment: Hi @theo thanks for you reply. Before I was using the line below `#$humanvisits = $visits.visits_timeseries[0].data` which have the same results when I run the code outside of th function but when I run it on the function and the error then is on the indexing part "$visits.visits_timeseries[0]".

Comment: I don't have the error when I use ``$sumhumanvisits = ($humanvisits[0..($humanvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_} | measure -Sum).Sum`` but the result is wrong because it summarise the reference values also like in this example ``1564531200000
69
1571788800000
145
1565049600000
229`` it will summarise all instead of the small values. When I use the proper code to select only the values ``$sumhumanvisits = ($humanvisits[0..($humanvisits.Length)] | foreach { $_[1]} | measure -Sum).Sum`` I have the error on $_[1]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I was passing the parameters to the functions separated by comma (noob mistake) sorry for that.

the function was giving the Cannot index into a null array error becasue the search was not returning the values as the parameters where wrong.